# Evaluate $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}p^{m-1} e^{\lambda z^m}$

Tags: summation

I've spent hours on a problem, but it boils down to evaluating this sum:

$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}p^{m-1} e^{\lambda z^m}$

where,

$z, \lambda\in \mathbb{R}, p\in [0,1]$

I don't know how to evaluate it. Is this trivial?

Comment: can you tell us somthing about the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner updated!